# No routes define for this uri

Tags: php

I’m following this tutorial from laracast(https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners) and I’m at this episode(16 - Make a Router) in the series. Which shows how to build a basic router. I have done everthing to my knowledge as illustrated in the video, but I’m experiencing problems with building the router.
I’m getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No routes
>   define for this uri' in C:\wamp64\www\todo\core\Router.php on line 23
>   Exception: No routes define for this uri in
>   C:\wamp64\www\todo\core\Router.php on line 23

How do I get passed this error? Here are my codes

routes.php:

```
$router->define([
    '' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php'
]);
```

Router.php

```
class Router
{

    protected $routes = [];


    // this function defines our routes
    public function define($routes)
    {
        # code...
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri){
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)) {
            # code...
            return $this->routes[$uri]; 
        }
        throw new Exception("No routes define for this uri");

    }
}
```

Index.php

```
$database = require 'core/bootstrap.php';

$router = new Router;

require 'routes.php';

$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

require $router->direct($uri);
```

If you need more information inform me.

**UPDATE**
This is my site structure in wampserver www folder:

[image]

Comment: Change your error message to give you more information. Maybe `"No routes define for this uri: $uri"` would tell you what route you're missing.

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No routes define for this uri: todo'

Comment: That's what I'm getting

Comment: Ok, so you need to add that to your `routes.php`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late respond. I using wampserver and in the www/ directory I have the root directory of my project name todo and within that I have an index.php which I specify as the entry point to my application like this: '' => 'controllers/index.php' in routes.php. But whenever I do localhost/todo and expection it to load index.php it returns that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem in this course. I beleve you already have htcaccess  file
and these codes inside

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /todo/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [END]
```

Anyway the routes should be like this

```
$router->define([
    'todo' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'todo/about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    'todo/contact' => 'controllers/contact.php'
]);
```

or you can  connect to PHP built-in Web Server from cmd, it will solve route issue for you  as well

Regards